# Downloading Large file to server with php

Tags: php

I need to download larger files to my server .I have dedicated Server ..which is 100mbps .But its taking too much time to download 8mb file.I use below code.Is there any Class to download files quickly ? which chunks the file and download it real quick ?

```
<?php
    $url  = 'http://www.example.com/a-large-file.zip';
    $path = '/path/to/a-large-file.zip';

    $fp = fopen($path, 'w');

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Edit : File is mp4 file

Comment: when logging in as root does `wget url` make it any faster ?

Comment: gimme time lemme check

Comment: hey i tried exec("wget $url -O $filename"); ,,, but file not saved in my current folder .. any idea ?

Comment: in your code example you aren't actually writing `$data` to your file... is this the problem?

Comment: @bcmcfc what u mean ? file is downloaded and saved .. but its too slow

Comment: try just wget from the command line

Comment: @user1281385 : yea its quick

Comment: Can you give the code to run in php exec("wget $url -O $filename"); . i get error wget: option requires an argument -- 'O'

Comment: probably has some rate limiting based on curl, try `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');`

Comment: $filename probably doesnt have a  value, i dont suggest wgetting from php though

Comment: hmm @user1281385 changing user agent did not help though :/

Answer (score 0):

If your line is as quick as you say, then it's likely to be a bottleneck at the other end.

Don't forget, file transfer speed is affect by not only your download speed, but also the other ends upload speed.

As such, it's unlikely there is anything you go do to improve this. Certainly no class or code will help you improve it by more than a few milliseconds - your best bet is to look at the network.

Specifically, check the number of concurrent connections from your end - it's all well and good having a decent line, but if it's being used for 100 connections, it's always going to be slower than one being used for 1 connection.

Likewise, check the download from another machine/server - if it's just a slow from a different server, then it's almost certainly a bottleneck at the other end.

Comment: hey as @user1281385 said .. wget is quick..but can u see my comment in question and solve it